# Python SQLAlchemy - Mocking a model attribute's "desc" method

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, sqlalchemy, mox

In my application, there is a class for each model that holds commonly used queries (I guess it's somewhat of a "Repository" in DDD language). Each of these classes is passed the SQLAlchemy session object to create queries with upon construction. I'm having a little difficulty in figuring the best way to assert certain queries are being run in my unit tests. Using the ubiquitous blog example, let's say I have a "Post" model with columns and attributes "date" and "content". I also have a "PostRepository" with the method "find_latest" that is supposed to query for all posts in descending order by "date". It looks something like:

```
from myapp.models import Post

class PostRepository(object):
    def __init__(self, session):
        self._s = session

    def find_latest(self):
        return self._s.query(Post).order_by(Post.date.desc())
```

I'm having trouble mocking the Post.date.desc() call. Right now I'm monkey patching a mock in for Post.date.desc in my unit test, but I feel that there is likely a better approach.

Edit: I'm using mox for mock objects, my current unit test looks something like:

```
import unittest
import mox

class TestPostRepository(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self._mox = mox.Mox()

    def _create_session_mock(self):
        from sqlalchemy.orm.session import Session
        return self._mox.CreateMock(Session)

    def _create_query_mock(self):
        from sqlalchemy.orm.query import Query
        return self._mox.CreateMock(Query)

    def _create_desc_mock(self):
        from myapp.models import Post
        return self._mox.CreateMock(Post.date.desc)

    def test_find_latest(self):
        from myapp.models.repositories import PostRepository
        from myapp.models import Post

        expected_result = 'test'

        session_mock = self._create_session_mock()
        query_mock = self._create_query_mock()
        desc_mock = self._create_desc_mock()

        # Monkey patch
        tmp = Post.date.desc
        Post.date.desc = desc_mock

        session_mock.query(Post).AndReturn(query_mock)
        query_mock.order_by(Post.date.desc().AndReturn('test')).AndReturn(query_mock)
        query_mock.offset(0).AndReturn(query_mock)
        query_mock.limit(10).AndReturn(expected_result)

        self._mox.ReplayAll()
        r = PostRepository(session_mock)

        result = r.find_latest()
        self._mox.VerifyAll()

        self.assertEquals(expected_result, result)

        Post.date.desc = tmp
```

This does work, though feels ugly and I'm not sure why it fails without the "AndReturn('test')" piece of "Post.date.desc().AndReturn('test')"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think you're really gaining much benefit by using mocks for testing your queries. Testing should be testing the **logic** of the code, not the **implementation**. A better solution would be to create a fresh database, add some objects to it, run the query on that database, and determine if you're getting the correct results back. For example:

```
# Create the engine. This starts a fresh database
engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
# Fills the database with the tables needed.
# If you use declarative, then the metadata for your tables can be found using Base.metadata
metadata.create_all(engine)
# Create a session to this database
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()

# Create some posts using the session and commit them
...

# Test your repository object...
repo = PostRepository(session)
results = repo.find_latest()

# Run your assertions of results
...
```

Now, you're actually testing the **logic** of the code. This means that you can change the implementation of your method, but so long as the query works correctly, the tests should still pass. If you want, you could write this method as a query that gets all the objects, then slices the resulting list. The test would pass, as it should. Later on, you could change the implementation to run the query using the SA expression APIs, and the test would pass.

One thing to keep in mind is that you might have problems with sqlite behaving differently than another database type. Using sqlite in-memory gives you fast tests, but if you want to be serious about these tests, you'll probably want to run them against the same type of database you'll be using in production as well.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I was getting too hung up on the details of the code. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: What you are saying is that instead of doing a unit test (a unit of logic), do an integration test (with the database). It's a valid approach, and possibly to most sensible for an ORM, yet the performance of these tests suffer a tune of one or two magnitudes. Right?

Comment: You are correct that writing a test (whether you wish to call it a "unit" test or an "integration" test) that will somehow access a slower resource (whether it be a disk drive, external service or database) will mean a slower test than one which does not access such a resource.

Comment: @MarkHildreth you'd probably call it an integration test, which is fine. Solving a mocking problem by not mocking is sometimes appropriate, but it seems weird not to call it what it is.

Answer (score 1):

If yet you want to create a unit test with mock input, you can create instances of your model with fake data

In case that the result proxy return result with data from more than one of the models (for instance when you join two tables), you can use `collections` data struct called `namedtuple`

We are using it to mock results of join queries